# JQuery to Angular-Typescript

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular7, typescript1.8

I have the below piece of code and am looking various ways to convert them in typescript, but could not find ways.
please suggest how would i achieve this function

```
$('html').addClass('abc');
$(".abc .wrap").css("height", hieght - 70);
```

This is another sample.

```
$("#Box").css("index", "");
$("#mID").css("index", "");
```

Please suggest how would i write them in Typescript.
Angular 7

Comment: I think you'll get better answers if you're more explicit. Are you asking how to use jQuery in TypeScript? Are you asking how to convert jQuery code into idiomatic Angular code? The more specific you can be about your issue, the more people will be able to help :)

Comment: "Are you asking how to convert jQuery code into idiomatic Angular code?"
This is what i am trying to achieve, the above mentioned code is in Jquery i need to write in Angular7 typescript. Please suggest.

Comment: Any ideas how to implement

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia:

> As TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, existing JavaScript
>   programs are also valid TypeScript programs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript

So your javascript is valid typescirpt code. If you want to add it to your application you can do that by just putting it into a *.js file (no need to do any typescript stuff) and add it to `scripts` in `angular.json`. Read more: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts

Answer (score 0):

As @Stefan mentioned, the same works in typescript also.

However, if you don't want to use jquery, then you can use the normal style and class attributes for the html elements

If you want to add styles and classes conditionally, you can use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) and [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directives from angular.

Also, you can use the [query selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) approach

Comment: dileep, thanks for replying. you have a sample code which could help me?
it would be of great help

Comment: @Amit. It's my pleasure. Did this help?

Comment: No dileep, i am confused with the approach you suggest.
Am looking at approach in typescript for this kind of implementation.

Comment: Firstly, Tell me one thing. You want the classes to be added conditionally?

Comment: Yes. Some conditions have to be set.

Comment: Could you please share the entire code where you are adding the class conditionally or post a stackblitz